# How do I close upon button click of a rendered component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, element

I'm having trouble figuring out how to close a component that's rendered. I currently have am able to open the modal component on my first page, but then I want to close it upon the click of a button through the component. How would I do that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import AddModal from './addmodal';

  class Page extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = { isModalOpen: false };
    }
    ...//skip
    handleAdd= () =>{
      this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    }
    render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleAdd} > Add </button>
          <AddModal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} />
        </div>
        )
    }
  }


  import React, { Component } from 'react';

  class AddModal extends Component {
    // ... skip

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

    render(){
      return(
        <modal inOpen={this.props.isOpen} >
        <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>
          Okay
        </Button>
          ...//skip
        </modal>
      )
    }
  }

  export default AddModal;
```

Comment: Could you post your code in a sandbox like https://repl.it/languages/reactjs to make it easier to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your modal component call an onClose callback so the parent can close it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import AddModal from './addmodal';

  class Page extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = { isModalOpen: false };
    }
    ...//skip
    handleAdd= () =>{
      this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    }
    handleClose= () =>{
      this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
    }
    render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleAdd} > Add </button>
          <AddModal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} handleClose={this.handleClose}/>
        </div>
        )
    }
  }


  import React, { Component } from 'react';

  class AddModal extends Component {
    // ... skip

    render(){
      return(
        <modal inOpen={this.props.isOpen} >
        <Button onClick={this.props.handleClose}> // call to parent
          Okay
        </Button>
          ...//skip
        </modal>
      )
    }
  }

  export default AddModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent component will decide whether the modal is open or not, hence it owns the state of the child.

Building on what @jsdeveloper posted, I think you can cut the clutter by using the same function to handle the opening and closing of the modal.

We will make use of a `toggleModal` function which changes the `isModalOpen` to `true` when it's `false` and vice versa. It uses a callback, which takes in the previous state value of `isModalOpen`.

```
toggleModal = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isModalOpen: !prevState.isModalOpen
  }))
}
```

So the final file should look something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AddModal from './addmodal';

class Page extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false
    };
  }
  // ... //skip
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isModalOpen: !prevState.isModalOpen
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}> Add </button>{' '}
        <AddModal
          isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
          toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddModal extends Component {
  // ... skip

  render() {
    return (
      <modal inOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
        <Button onClick={this.props.toggleModal}>Close</Button>
        //... skip
      </modal>
    );
  }
}

export default AddModal;
```